# my project files are being closed upon closing visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Weird thing. I'm working regularly with my Visual Studio. However, at some point in time, with a single project, when I close the Visual Studio, when I re-open it all the files are closed, i.e., I get everything as usual except that I need to re-open all the files that I worked on.

Does anyone know how to make Visual Studio keep my files open?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715594/visual-studio-not-remembering-open-documents-startup-project

Comment: No, for me deleting the .suo did not work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You'll have to focus on what happens with the .suo file, that's the one that remembers what windows were opened.  Maybe you checked it into source control, maybe it is corrupted, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting all your settings? Tools --> Import and Export Setting --> Select Reset all setting.

Otherwise, you might want to try a clean uninstall/reinstall. But I venture you might have tried that already, given you did your own research before asking your question.

Lastly, some weird behaviors I used to have in VS were sometimes fixed by a starting it as an admin, I never clearly understood why.

Comment: I tried it all now, to no avail. It must be project related because my other projects keep their tabs open while restarting them. I am also able to notice that in the quick second while I press the close button of the visual studio and until it closes all tabs are being closed as if I pressed window-> close all documents. Also, I recently got new computer so this is a fresh copy of VS. I had the same issue with my old computer.