# MVC App Crashes On Open - "ISelectionService cannot be located"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a .NET MVC application that I am trying to open in Visual Studio 2015 Community. It worked fine yesterday when I was doing some changes to it, but today I tried opening it and encountered a popup saying that `System.ComponentModel.Design.ISelectionService cannot be located`

I can open my WinForm apps just fine, but this one is acting like it's got some kind of problem with my SQL Reports that are part of the project. I'm not really sure what could cause this to suddenly occur or what I can do to resolve it and get back to work on my application. Here is a popup of the error:

[image]

**Edit:**

I could rollback to a different version and it works fine, but I'm still curious as to why this might occur, in the event that it happens later on down the road...

Answer (score 0):

Are you still getting this error message? I get the same thing every so often - last time I reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 and the issue went away. This time I deleted my .suo file as suggested in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33659738/6241360

Did the trick for me.

Comment: Still encounter the issue, have just been using a "band aid" method in the meantime - I'll investigate the link you left & see if it's an Answer