# Visual Studio forgets which documents are open

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. My problem is the opened documents are somehow forgotten and when I open VS again, the previously open documents are opening (which I used them 2 weeks ago).

So, let's say I left open the documents `A.cs, B.cs, C.cs`. But after I open VS again it shows `F.cs, G.cs, H.cs`(the documents from 2 weeks ago). How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6715594/11107541

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i have problems with the last open documents with Visual Studio i delete the  .suo or .user (or both). Then Visual Studio used the default settings you have to set your settings again.