# Visual Studio not saving session state after closing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

My computer recently froze while debugging a project (on Visual Studio 2017).

No data was lost (because everything is saved and compiled before debug anyway), but now every time I open the project the Visual Studio environment looks like it did on the day it froze. The most recent session state is never saved, so I have to manually find and reopen all the pages I was just working on.

No data is lost and my work is still progressing as normal. It's just mildly annoying having to do this every time.

I presume there's a file somewhere that needs deleting. Not sure which one to safely remove though.

Thanks.

Comment: To answer your question: Editing the question bumps it back to the top of the page, even when the question is somewhat old.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, I didn't know that. I've altered my answer here too, to point people in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer here: [visual studio not remembering open documents & startup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715594/visual-studio-not-remembering-open-documents-startup-project)

Deleted `.csproj.user` file and everything in the `.vs/[projectName]/v15` folder. It may be a hidden folder so be sure to tell your File Explorer to show hidden files.