# My code windows used to open automatically in vs2017 — not anymore

Tags: visual-studio

It is so handy to have all my same code windows open immediately when I load the solution, as is always the case in Visual Studio 2017.  But now in 2019, I have to go to the Solution Explorer, right click each class, and select View Code.  I'm wondering why this is necessary.  Is there a switch somewhere that will return to the good old days?  All my pinned code windows used to pop up just as I left them, and the unpinned ones as well, but sometimes rearranged.  Such a big advantage.

I've searched for answers, but no mention of this problem.

This is not a coding problem.  It's a platform problem.

Believe me, I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: please, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56474173/1636492

Comment: This is the answer, and as soon as I saw it I knew.
"Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> Reopen documents on solution load"
Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342959/patrick