# Visual Studio IDE loading old desktop layout

Tags: visual-studio

I am using VS 2017 and whenever I've closed a project in the past, the same tabbed windows are automatically opened making it easy to get going where you last left off.

As of several months ago, the same old set of windows that I had opened months ago reopen each time I restart VS.  This means that I must close all of the old VS windows that I no longer need and manually open the ones I do.

It's like if my IDE state is not being saved anymore.  I've deleted everything in my **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local** folder but this made no difference at all.  Additionally, I verified that my project files were not set to '**read only**' but this did not help.

Any suggestions?

P.S.  I had forgotten to mention that old and obsolete breakpoints will always be set each time you open a project.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715594/visual-studio-not-remembering-open-documents-startup-project

Comment: @SergeyVlasov, thank you so much.  I closed VS, then deleted the .user and .suo files and now my last desktop layout is remembered.

Answer (score 0):

The person who deserves credit is Sergy Vlasov for solving my problem.

There was one additional issue that I had not mentioned, one that bothered me for a few months.  Some parts of my **code had red error lines** underneath even though my code would **build fine**.

The resolution to this was to simply close VS, then delete the **.vs** hidden folder within my project.  Upon restarting VS, those lines were gone.